# Copying multiple lines from outside source

Tags: vba, excel

Im having an issue where i want to copy data from one workbook into another.  The workbook I am trying to copy from has two sheets, I am pulling data from both into an array.  The problem is when I try to copy over data in the array from the Scanned Sheet (because it is more accurate), it isnt listing all the scanned lines.

Any help is appreciated.

**Code/Images**

*Images:*

[image: This is the data to grab]

[image: This is the results]

*Code:*

'* Report work begins here.

```
lngLineNum = 0

RecursiveDir colFiles, strPath, "*_*_*_*.xlsm", True

For Each varFile In colFiles
    Set wbkReportBook = Workbooks.Open(varFile)
    Set wstSUData = wbkReportBook.Sheets("SUData")
    Set wstScanSheet = wbkReportBook.Sheets("Scan Sheet")

    lngReportRow = 8

    Do While wstSUData.Cells(lngReportRow, 1) <> ""
        lngLineNum = lngLineNum + 1
```

'* Preserve report data from SUData.

```
            With wstSUData
                strPtNum = .Cells(lngReportRow, 1)
                strPartNo = .Cells(lngReportRow, 2)
                strSU = .Cells(lngReportRow, 3)
                strQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 4)
                strShipper = .Cells(lngReportRow, 5)
                strHtsCode = .Cells(lngReportRow, 6)
                strCOO = .Cells(lngReportRow, 7)
                strItemWeight = .Cells(lngReportRow, 8)
                strPrice = .Cells(lngReportRow, 9)
                strMOD = .Cells(lngReportRow, 10)
                strDealer = .Cells(lngReportRow, 11)
                strDesc = .Cells(lngReportRow, 12)
                strPDC = .Cells(lngReportRow, 13)
                strScanQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 14)
                strRemain = .Cells(lngReportRow, 15)
                strStatus = .Cells(lngReportRow, 16)
                strAuditor = .Cells(lngReportRow, 17)
                strWeightUpdate = .Cells(lngReportRow, 18)
                strCOO_Num = .Cells(lngReportRow, 19)
                strSpecial = .Cells(lngReportRow, 20)
                strScale = .Cells(lngReportRow, 21)
                datDate = dateScrub(.Cells(5, 1))
            End With

            dblDate = CDbl(datDate)

            ReDim Preserve strReportArray(26, lngLineNum)
            strReportArray(0, lngLineNum) = varFile
            strReportArray(1, lngLineNum) = strPtNum
            strReportArray(2, lngLineNum) = strPartNo
            strReportArray(3, lngLineNum) = strSU
            strReportArray(4, lngLineNum) = strExpectQuantity
            strReportArray(5, lngLineNum) = strShipper
            strReportArray(6, lngLineNum) = strHtsCode
            strReportArray(7, lngLineNum) = strCOO
            strReportArray(8, lngLineNum) = strItemWeight
            strReportArray(9, lngLineNum) = strPrice
            strReportArray(10, lngLineNum) = strMOD
            strReportArray(11, lngLineNum) = strDealer
            strReportArray(12, lngLineNum) = strPDC
            strReportArray(13, lngLineNum) = strWTF
            strReportArray(14, lngLineNum) = strScanQuantity
            strReportArray(15, lngLineNum) = strRemain
            strReportArray(16, lngLineNum) = strStatus
            strReportArray(17, lngLineNum) = strAuditor
            strReportArray(18, lngLineNum) = strWeightUpdate
            strReportArray(19, lngLineNum) = strCOO_Num
            strReportArray(20, lngLineNum) = strSpecial
            strReportArray(21, lngLineNum) = strScale
            strReportArray(22, lngLineNum) = dblDate
            strReportArray(23, lngLineNum) = 0
            strReportArray(24, lngLineNum) = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(varFile).DateLastModified
            strReportArray(25, lngLineNum) = ""
            strReportArray(26, lngLineNum) = ""

        lngReportRow = lngReportRow + 1

    Loop
```

'* Preserve report data from Scan Sheet.

```
    lngReportRow = 9
    lngLineNum = 0

    Do While wstScanSheet.Cells(lngReportRow, 1) <> ""
            lngLineNum = lngLineNum + 1


            With wstScanSheet
                strPickTicket = .Cells(lngReportRow, 1)
                strScanCOO = .Cells(lngReportRow, 2)
                strPartNo = .Cells(lngReportRow, 3)
                strScanQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 4)
                strExpectQuantity = .Cells(lngReportRow, 5)
                strRemain = .Cells(lngReportRow, 6)
                strSU = .Cells(lngReportRow, 7)
                strStatus = .Cells(lngReportRow, 8)
                strSystemCOO = .Cells(lngReportRow, 9)
                strCOOStatus = .Cells(lngReportRow, 10)
                strItemWeight = .Cells(lngReportRow, 11)
                strSpecial = .Cells(lngReportRow, 12)
                strScale = .Cells(lngReportRow, 13)
                strAuditor = .Cells(1, 3)
            End With

            ReDim Preserve strReportArray(26, lngLineNum)
            strReportArray(0, lngLineNum) = varFile
            strReportArray(1, lngLineNum) = strPtNum
            strReportArray(2, lngLineNum) = strPartNo
            strReportArray(3, lngLineNum) = strSU
            strReportArray(4, lngLineNum) = strExpectQuantity
            'strReportArray(5, lngLineNum) = ""
            'strReportArray(6, lngLineNum) = ""
            'strReportArray(7, lngLineNum) = ""
            strReportArray(8, lngLineNum) = strItemWeight
            'strReportArray(9, lngLineNum) = ""
            'strReportArray(10, lngLineNum) = ""
            'strReportArray(11, lngLineNum) = ""
            'strReportArray(12, lngLineNum) = ""
            'strReportArray(13, lngLineNum) = ""
            strReportArray(14, lngLineNum) = strScanQuantity
            strReportArray(15, lngLineNum) = strRemain
            strReportArray(16, lngLineNum) = strStatus
            strReportArray(17, lngLineNum) = strAuditor
            'strReportArray(18, lngLineNum) = ""
            'strReportArray(19, lngLineNum) = ""
            strReportArray(20, lngLineNum) = strSpecial
            strReportArray(21, lngLineNum) = strScale
            strReportArray(22, lngLineNum) = dblDate
            strReportArray(23, lngLineNum) = 0
            strReportArray(24, lngLineNum) = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(varFile).DateLastModified
            strReportArray(25, lngLineNum) = strSystemCOO
            strReportArray(26, lngLineNum) = strCOOStatus
        ''End If

        lngReportRow = lngReportRow + 1

    Loop

    wbkReportBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

'* Report work ends here.

```
Next varFile
```

'* Paste the data.

```
lngBaseRow = 2

Do While wstSuScan.Cells(lngBaseRow, 1) <> ""
    lngBaseRow = lngBaseRow + 1
Loop


For lngLineNum = 1 To UBound(strReportArray, 2)

    varWeek = strReportArray(22, lngLineNum)
    Do Until Weekday(varWeek, vbSunday) = 2
        varWeek = varWeek - 1
    Loop

    With wstSuScan
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 1) = varWeek
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 2) = strReportArray(22, lngLineNum) 'date
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 3) = strReportArray(12, lngLineNum) 'depot
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 4) = strReportArray(11, lngLineNum) 'dealer
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 5) = strReportArray(10, lngLineNum) 'mod
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 6) = strReportArray(5, lngLineNum) 'shipper
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 7) = strReportArray(1, lngLineNum) 'ticket
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 8) = strReportArray(2, lngLineNum) 'part
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 9) = strReportArray(14, lngLineNum) 'scanned
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 10) = strReportArray(4, lngLineNum) 'expected
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 11) = strReportArray(15, lngLineNum) 'remain
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 12) = strReportArray(3, lngLineNum) 'su
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 13) = strReportArray(16, lngLineNum) 'status
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 14) = strReportArray(17, lngLineNum) 'auditor
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 15) = strReportArray(18, lngLineNum) 'weight update
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 16) = strReportArray(7, lngLineNum) 'coo
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 17) = strReportArray(20, lngLineNum) 'special
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 18) = strReportArray(21, lngLineNum) 'scale
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 19) = strReportArray(25, lngLineNum)
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 20) = strReportArray(26, lngLineNum)
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 21) = strReportArray(8, lngLineNum)
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 22) = strReportArray(20, lngLineNum)
        .Cells(lngBaseRow, 23) = strReportArray(21, lngLineNum)

    End With

    lngBaseRow = lngBaseRow + 1

Next lngLineNum
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and severely edit the question.

Comment: a lot of the code is just filling elements in an array.  its pretty simply to read.

Comment: yes, but you want us to read through all of it and try to solve it. if you give us something to work or tell us which line seems to be causing the issue, it would make it a lot easier. That said, have you debugged the code yourself, running it line-by-line to see where it starts to produce the undesired results?

Comment: Code seems to be a little over-worked: you read in values to variables to then put the variables into an array to then put the array values onto a worksheet.  You don't need the intermediate values or the arrays at all here: all they do is make you code more-difficult to debug.

Comment: its someone elses code i am reverse engineering.  i assume he made the array because there is multiple values to copy.  I just don't know why everything isn't pasting.  If I don't copy the values from the wstScanSheet into the array it seems to work.

Comment: Can you let us know (a) how many files are being processed by your "For Each varFile In colFiles" loop, (b) how many rows of data exist in each of the SUData sheets in each of those files, (c) how many rows of data exist in each of the Scan Sheet sheets in each of those files, and (d) how many rows of data are appearing in your output.

Comment: A. Right now only one.  B.  4.  C. 4.  D. 1

Comment: I just tried running the code with a single file, 4 data lines in SUData (rows 8 to 11), 4 data lines in Scan Sheet (rows 9 to 12), and I ended up with 4 lines in the output.  As I expected, only the first line contains data from SUData, and the Ticket column has the same value (the value from the last row in SUData) in each of the 4 lines.  I'm not sure why you are only ending up with a single row in your output.

Answer (score 0):

If I have read your code correctly, the problem is (probably) occurring because lngLineNum is being initialised at the start of your code (before any files are accessed), AND at the start of your processing of the Scan Data sheet.  And you are also ReDimming StringReportArray whenever you read the Scan Data sheets.

Assume your first file has x rows of data, and your second file has y rows, and your third file has z rows.

You will populate positions 1 to x of StringReportArray from the SUData sheet of file 1.

You then reset StringReportArray, and populate some of the fields in positions 1 to x of StringReportArray from the Scan Data sheet of file 1.

You then start processing the second file and populate positions x+1 to x+y from SUData of file 2.

You then reset StringReportArray and populate positions 1 to y (not x+1 to x+y) from Scan Data of file 2.

You then start processing the third file and populate positions y+1 to y+z (instead of x+y+1 to x+y+z) from SUData of file 3.

You then reset StringReportArray and populate positions 1 to z (not x+y+1 to x+y+z) from Scan Data of file 3.

The above all assumes that you have the same number of rows in your SUData and Scan Data sheets, and each row in SUData corresponds to the equivalent row in Scan Data.  (E.g. SUData row 8 is related to Scan Data row 9, SUData row 9 is related to Scan Data row 10, ... SUData row 200 is related to Scan Data row 201, ...)  If you don't, then your whole methodology is flawed, not just parts of the code.

Also, when you are processing every row of Scan Data, you store into StringReportArray the value of strPtNum that you obtained from the last row you processed from SUData.

As best I can make out the first row of your output will consist of the values from the first row of SUData from the first file you process, with some values obtained from the first row of Scan Data from the last file you process.  Other rows in your output will consist solely of information obtained from the other rows in Scan Data from the last file you process.  However the "Ticket" column will contain the same value in all rows of the output, being obtained from the last row of SUData from the last file processed.

The total number of rows in your output will be the number of rows in the Scan Data sheet of the last file processed.

(And, if only one file is being picked up by your RecursiveDir function, "first file" will be the same file as "last file" because it is the only file.)

If this describes the output you are getting, your problems are almost certainly due to the issues described in the first paragraph.

Comment: IngLineNum is initialized to 0 for each worksheet pull.  I commented out the ones i am not replacing data with in the second worksheet.  I am trying to pull data from both worksheets and have the scan sheet replace data that matches the first sheet.

Comment: The code you included in your question only shows lngLineNum being set to 0 in two spots.  If your code is actually doing it more often, please update your question - it will probably affect how we understand what the code is doing.